# Bluetooth in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

***Can't enable Bluetooth in  ubuntu.***
I have plugged in a bluetooth reciver but ubuntu dosent detect it. 
I have run this command :sudo rfkill list

```
:~$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I run lsusb on terminal .

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp
```

Comment: Please [edit] and post the exact hardware you added. If it's an USB dongle you can use `lsusb` to find out.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia. I run lsusb on terminal .Output =>```Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp```

Answer (score 0):

came across "ID 8087:1024 Intel Corp." its a cheap Bluetooth USB adapter (obviously)and only shows this device id when i believe resistors are damaged or removed from the actual circuit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).